# Best way to "SELECT *" from multiple tabs in sql without duplicate?

Tags: sql, join, select

I am trying to retrieve every data stored in 2 tabs from my database through a SELECT statement.
The problem is there are a lot of columns in each tab and manually selecting each column would be a pain in the ass.

So naturally I thought about using a join :

```
select * from equipment
join data
on equipment.id = data.equipmentId
```

The problem is I am getting the equipment ID 2 times in the result.
I thought that maybe some specific join could help me filter out the duplicate key, but I can't manage to find a way...
Is there any way to filter out the foreign key or is there a better way to do the whole thing (I would rather not have to post process the data to manually remove those duplicate columns)?

Comment: You should include a minimal sample of data from both tables which explains the problem.  Using `SELECT DISTINCT` might one option, but if e.g. a piece of equipment joins to 2 records in the `data` table, you need to decide how to handle the columns from the `data` table across 2 rows.

Comment: _manually selecting each column would be a pain in the ass_ - but also the proper way to do it!

Comment: Worse case, put that query into Query Builder and untick the "data.equipmentId"

Comment: However, `JOIN USING (col)` syntax only returns one col column.

Comment: Yes I have roughly 50 columns, if manually doing it is the right way, then I'll probably give a try to Query Builder. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wait yes ```JOIN USING()``` is doing the trick, I had never heard of it, thx.

Comment: If there are a lot of columns you would do better to only select the columns that you need. The query will run quicker, there will be less data to transfer and client side it will be cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use USING clause.

> "The USING clause specifies which columns to test for equality when
> two tables are joined. It can be used instead of an ON clause in the
> JOIN operations that have an explicit join clause."

```
select * 
from test
join test2 using(id)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=075e9bbc43d9421b9b2dfb77119259f5)

Comment: Hi @jarlh do you want me to delete this answer ? I see your comment was before this...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **NATURAL JOIN**

```
select * 
from test
natural join test2;
```